# “You cannot take a word out of a song”?

Tags: language, parashat-nitzavim

Rabbi Ari Neuwirth in [Parashat Nitzavim: Why a Song?](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?v=47905) says that Torah is called Shirah (Song) in our parsha because no mitzvos can be taken out and none can be added to our perfect Torah.

There is a Russian idiom "*из песни слова не выкинешь*", literally "*one cannot throw a word out of song*".

The meaning is that "*when telling a story, one may not omit even unpleasant/unsavory details*", or, more broadly, "*a coherent structure loses its coherence when critical parts are removed*".

Is there a Hebrew analogue of this expression?

Answer (score 1):

One such Talmudic idiom, not limited to poetry, goes ([Ber. 40b](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9E_%D7%91)):

> כל המשנה ממטבע שטבעו חכמים אינו אלא טועה

Soncino Trans.:

> If one alters the formula laid down by the Sages [in benedictions], he has not performed his obligation